# Memory exhausted during csv upload?

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

I am uploading a csv and creating custom nodes. I have set the drupal memory limit to 512M and I can see this in the drupal status report. But when I am uploading a csv file, I am getting the error message 'Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)'. The file I am trying to upload is only 26MB. I am using batch process for creating nodes. How do I resolve this memory exhausting issue? If by increasing the memory can resolve this issue, what is the recommended memory limit I should set?

Comment: Your problem probably isn't the memory limit. Do you use a contrib module to upload the CSV or is it custom? If custom, then I'd guess you didn't implement a proper batch to process your CSV. A 26MB CSV file is quite large. Maybe have a look at this example module https://github.com/GiantRobot/csvimport on how to properly batch process a CSV. It has has branches for D6, D7, and D8.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating one node per PHP pass? If you are handling the batch API on your custom code you would need to control `$context['sandbox']`. This is an example: https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/batch_example%21batch_example.module/function/batch_example_op_2/7.x-1.x and here another one in the context of a hook_update: http://bleen.net/blog/running-batch-processes-update-hook-bed